# IndexOutOfRangeException SqlDataReader reading bool value from table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqldatareader

I've 3 tables: `users`, `feed(id,body,title,link)` and `userstofeed(id,userid,feedid,isread)` while i'm trying to read bool value from userstofeed table it bring `IndexOutOfRangeException`. Tell me please what I'm doing wrong

```
while (reader.Read())
{
     rssFeed.Title = reader["title"].ToString();
     rssFeed.Body = reader["body"].ToString();
     rssFeed.Link = reader["link"].ToString();
     rssFeed.IsRead = (bool) reader["isread"]; //IndexOutOfRangeException here
     yield return rssFeed;
}
```

And here sql store procedure:

```
create proc spGetItemsByUser
@userName nvarchar(50)
as
begin
declare @userId int
declare @feedId table (id int)

select @userId = id 
from Users 
where name = @userName

insert into @feedid (id)
select feedid, isread 
from userstofeed 
where userid = @userId

select * from feed where id in (select id from @feedId)
select isread from userstofeed where userid = @userId //Here I'm getting bit if it read or not
end
```

Comment: Your procedure should generate an error since the number of values in the select statement is different then the number of columns in the insert statement: `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the `SELECT`s in your stored procedure to this:

```
SELECT [feed].[title], [feed].[body], [feed].[link], [userstofeed].[isread]
FROM [feed]
INNER JOIN [userstofeed] ON ([userstofeed].userid = @userId)
WHERE [feed].[id] in (select id from @feedId)
```

I think in your version `isread` is not a column of the first result set. The `isread` values are appended as rows after the rows for `title`, `feed` and `body`.

---

As Zohar Peled suggested, I try to give a refactoring for the whole stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROC spGetItemsByUser
   @userName nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT [feed].[title], [feed].[body], [feed].[link], [userstofeed].[isread]
    FROM [feed]
    INNER JOIN [userstofeed] ON ([userstofeed].[feedid] = [feed].[id])
    INNER JOIN [users] ON ([users].[id] = [userstofeed].[userid])
    WHERE [users].[name] = @userName
END
```

Comment: Actually they are now not a row after - they are a second resultset with one row of one columns. It is accessible, but requires different coding.